# "document.forms.value" - Undefined in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, variables, microsoft-edge

I wrote a very quick javascript function to validate a very small form on an internal form used in our office. However, someoner today told me that it doesnt work in Edge, the code does not ever enable the submit button.

I console.log out the var values every time the function runs, and in edge, the vars are forever undefined. It seems like Edge does not respect "document.forms["abc"]["xyz"].value", but I cannot find any documentation or notes to support that.

I should clarify, I am not a javascript pro, I uyse it very sparingly, and in simple ways to get smal tasks done like this, so please dont judge my code too hard, haha.

**Console Log:**

```
q1=undefined
q2=undefined
q3=undefined
q4=undefined
```

**My code is below, its pretty simple, nothing fancy..**

```
function fieldcheck(){
    var q1=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q1overall"].value;
    var q2=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q2understand"].value;
    var q3=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q3time"].value;
    var q4=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q4recommend"].value;
    console.log("q1="+q1+"\n"+"q2="+q2+"\n"+"q3="+q3+"\n"+"q4="+q4);
    document.getElementById("datacollectsubmit1").disabled = true;
    if (q1 && q2 && q3 && q4){
        console.log("q1234 set");
        document.getElementById("datacollectsubmit1").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

**I call the above on every click with:**

```
document.onclick = function(){
    fieldcheck();
}
```

Anyone have any clue as to why Edge is playing games? Or what I can substiture for document.forms.value that will work across other browsers and Edge too? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is working in MS Edge. Possible that some other code caused this issue. I suggest you to take the code below and run it in MS Edge.

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
<script>
function fieldcheck(){
    var q1=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q1overall"].value;
    var q2=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q2understand"].value;
    var q3=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q3time"].value;
    var q4=document.forms["datacollect1"]["q4recommend"].value;
    console.log("q1="+q1+"\n"+"q2="+q2+"\n"+"q3="+q3+"\n"+"q4="+q4);
    document.getElementById("datacollectsubmit1").disabled = true;
    if (q1 && q2 && q3 && q4){
        console.log("q1234 set");
        document.getElementById("datacollectsubmit1").disabled = false;
    }
}
document.onclick = function(){
    fieldcheck();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="datacollect1"  onsubmit="return  fieldcheck()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="q1overall"><br>
Name1: <input type="text" name="q2understand"><br>
Name2: <input type="text" name="q3time"><br>
Name3: <input type="text" name="q4recommend"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" id="datacollectsubmit1" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in MS Edge browser:

[image]